# Error running postinst script in Debian package

Tags: packaging, debian

I want to create my own deb package on Ubtunu 14.04 using `dh_make` and `dh_install`. I put the postinst file in `mypackage-1.0/debian/postinst`. I have no problem to create the deb. But when I try to install the package using the command of `dpkg -i mypackage_1.0-1_all.deb` I got following errors:

```
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute installed post-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/info/mypackage.postinst): No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mypackage 
(--install): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing: mypackage
```

Please note, the script file exists and it has proper execution permissions.

Thanks.

Comment: When you extract your .deb, do you get a control.tar.gz that includes the control file and the postinst script?

Comment: @Katu, `dpkg` get error when tried to run it, then the file exists in the package.

Comment: @BrianNate, That script fails in one of its instructions and exits with error code. Could you add the contents of `postinst` to the question.  You may also add some `echo`'s to it the know where exactly it does fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the maintenance scripts from your deb with

```
mkdir tmp   
dpkg-deb -R mypackage_1.0-1_all.deb tmp
```

Now you can run `tmp/DEBIAN/postinst` with a "configure" argument to simulate a package install, and see what the problem is:

```
tmp/DEBIAN/postinst configure
```